# Changing DisplayMember and ValueMember properties of a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Is it possible to discard the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties and make the combobox to use other properties instead?

What I'm trying to tell is: add attribute so that they are not visible in the property grid.

```
[Browsable(false)]
public new ValueMember {get; set;}

[Browsable(false)]
public new DisplayMember {get; set;}
```

Then, declare two new properties and populate them with desired values...

```
 public new MyValueMember {get; set;}   
 public new MyDisplayMember {get; set;}
```

...and make the combobox use the declared properties for the binding.

Is this possible? Any help is very appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm using entity framework and when you set a datasource for bindingsource at design time and you set the MemberValue

it gives you an error when trying to reopen the form telling you that the type of property name can not be find on the datasource of the bindingfield.

so to prevent it I thought of adding a property MyValuemember and MyDisplayMember 
and MyDatamember property so after setting the combobox datasource I would select Datamember from the Mydatamember property and than relatively I would select MyDisplayMember and MyValuemember from the list  and set MyDisplay&Valuemember to the base.DisplayMember & base.Valuemember but apperantly I can not do that because the datasource is the parent and those properties are not available..

so I've come up a different solution which worked:

In case anyone else stumbles to the same propblem following is my solution:

I've added a new Datasource property name Base4Datasource 
and I've added a new DataMember property named Base4Datamember

so after I setting the Base4Datasource I clone the value and set it than when I populate Base4Datamember and set it I again set the Datasource with the valuemember.

```
[Browsable(false)]
    public new object DataSource
    {
        get => base.DataSource;
        set => base.DataSource = value;
    }


    public object _base4DataSource = new BindingSource();

    [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    [Category("Base4Data")]
    [DisplayName("Base4 DataSource")]
    public object Base4DataSource
    {
        get => _base4DataSource;
        set
        {

            if (value != null)
            {
                var cloned = value.CustomMemberwiseClone();
                DataSource = cloned;
                _base4DataSource = cloned;
            }
            else
            {
                _base4DataSource = null;
                DataSource = null;

                Base4DataMember = string.Empty;
                BindingField = string.Empty;
            }


        }
    }

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public string _base4DataMember;

    [Category("Base4Data")]
    [DisplayName("Base4 Data Member")]
    [Description("Please Select a Datamember from the list")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ComboboxDataMemberConverter))]
    public virtual string Base4DataMember {
        get => _base4DataMember;
        set
        {
            _base4DataMember = value;

            if (value != null)
            {
                base.DataSource = new BindingSource(DataSource, value);
            }
            {
                ValueMember = string.Empty;
                DisplayMember = string.Empty;
                FillMethod = string.Empty;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: But, is this just to change the names of the properties at design-time? Otherwise, what's the use of it?

Comment: What's the problem which you are trying to solve? While the answer is yes, you can, but to me it looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Please post the answer as answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: However it's an example of XY problem.

Comment: The issue is: If you have a derived class, want to show in a property grid and want to make the properties from the base class invisible in den propertygrid, you set the browsable attribute to false. But this comes with the isssue, if you use a property from the base class for Displayname in a bound combobox you get an exception.

E.g.:

Your base class is some abstract class for some kind of car.  The derived class have some extra properties. This properties should be editable by the user in a property grid.